# Disabling Swipe view not handling tap gesture events on the content

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using a swipe view for delete line items in the collection view. There are other elements like checkbox, chevron icons where it has its own functionalities on tapping those items in every line item. But when I disable the swipe view(disabling it from binding based on some conditions), tapping events of other elements in line items also get disabled. This is occurring only on iOS but working fine in Android.

```
  <SwipeView IsEnabled="{Binding IsLineItemDeletionEnabled}">

    <SwipeView.RightItems>
        <SwipeItemView  
             Command="{x:Binding ViewModel.DeleteLineCommand}">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image VerticalOptions="Center" Source="ico_delete.png">
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </SwipeItemView>
    </SwipeView.RightItems>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridSpacingPaddingLeftMarginTopMedium}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <bp:CustomCheckBox Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" Command="{x:Binding ConfirmLineItemCommandFromCheckBox}" />

           <bp:AnimateImage Grid.Row="1" Source="chev_r.png">
                <bp:AnimateImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{x:Binding OpenNewPage}"/>
                </bp:AnimateImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </bp:AnimateImage>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
  </SwipeView>
```

**Xamarin Version - 4.7.0.1179**
I did try to update it to **4.8.0.1269** as well. But the issue is still occurring.

Is there any error that can notice from the above code or is this a known issue?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, I have checked this in my local site, it seems not work in iOS. I will continue to research it, if good news will update here.

Comment: I have submitted it  as an issue in Github [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11969). We can follow it up there later.

Comment: Great. I did the same few hours back. Let's see how it goes. Thanks again 

[link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11968)